# PHP foreach array print counter

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have following example PHP code and its working great! but i just want one more addition so it print line number too.

```
<?php
$path = shell_exec('cat data.txt');
$path = chop($path,"\n");
$lines =  explode("\n",$path);
echo "<h2><a href=\"http:\"\" title=\"Summery\">List of Studies</a></h2>";

foreach($lines as $line) {
        echo "<h3><p>$line</p></h3>";
}
        ?>
```

Output:

```
ABC
XYZ
123
```

I want following addition and add counter in it.

```
1. ABC
2. XYZ
3. 123
```

Comment: Have you considered using the `file` function? It will automatically split lines for you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can assign the index to variable too, not just the value:

```
foreach($lines as $index => $line) {
    printf('<h3><p>%d. %s</p></h3>', $index + 1, $line);
}
```

Comment: The counter will start at 0 for this code. You could make it start at 1 with {$index+1} in place of {$index}

Comment: Good point, but I don't think `{$index+1}` would work inside a string

Comment: You example is super simple but only problem is it first counter is `0` :(

Comment: Holy smoke!!! you guys are freaking awesome! `printf('<h3><p>%d. %s</p></h3>', $index + 1, $line);` did magic :)

Comment: @Satish If you do not use the `<ol>` tag answer, you sir are a fool!

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use the index php, you can use the tag ol

Reff: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_lists

Comment: This has to be the accepted answer!!!! By far the most obvious answer. How could someone >2k rep even be asking this 0_o

Comment: thank you! , Sometimes it is inevitable to use the index, but in this case, it is trivial to use

Comment: @lan - I am not a php developer, I am Linux admin, and i just came across with this issue and pop up question. I know you are freaking genius then what the `hell` you doing here...

Comment: In my example its not going to work because i am not playing with index its a loop. I don't know why bit its not doing what i want.. sorry

Comment: All questions are important!
in your case using the ol tag would solve your problem and save 0.0011 of its processing

Answer (score 2):

```
$i=1;
foreach($lines as $line) {
    echo "<h3><p>$i. $line</p></h3>";
$i++;
}
```

Comment: You example is perfectly fit in my Senior

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$path = shell_exec('cat data.txt');
$path = chop($path,"\n");
$lines =  explode("\n",$path);
echo "<h2><a href=\"http:\"\" title=\"Summery\">List of Studies</a></h2>";
$c = 0;
foreach($lines as $line) {
        $c++
        echo "<h3><p>".$c.". ".$line."</p></h3>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

```
foreach($lines as $i=>$line) {
        echo "<h3>$i. <p>$line</p></h3>";
}
```